# android item/group visibility not working

Tags: android

I am trying to hide a group or/and item but none of them work i kept searching and all the answers are the same. if doesn't crash (nullpointerexception) nothing happens (showing the same menu). below are my the xml for the menu items and the methods

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.handle_group, false);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**xml**

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/manage_account"
    android:icon="@drawable/manage_account"
    android:title="@string/manage_account" />

<group
    android:id="@+id/handle_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/handle_users"
        android:icon="@drawable/manage_users"
        android:title="@string/manage_users" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/handle_maintenances"
        android:icon="@drawable/toolbox"
        android:title="@string/check_issues" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/handle_complaints"
        android:icon="@drawable/complaint_list"
        android:title="@string/check_complaints" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/handle_exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit_icon"
        android:title="@string/manage_exit" />

</group>
```

I tried with both setVisiblity (for an item) and setGroupVisibility (for a group) but it doesn't work. is there something i am missing, is it a bug in the current android version, library, config...

Comment: You should be able to do: item=menu.findItem(R...); item.setVisible(false);

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is - did you put INVISIBLE or VISIBLE inside your setvisiblity? That works for my app

```
whateveritem.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: In a MenuItem this `MenuItem accountThing = menu.findItem(R.id.manage_account);
        accountThing.setVisiblity(Invisible);` setVisiblity doesn't exist (shows in red)

Comment: call this method then "public abstract MenuItem setVisible (boolean visible)" the android dev pages says it works.                                                      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html all the way at the bottom

Comment: when i use .setVisible on a MenuItem the menuItem is always null either in the prepare or in the create